# Sync adapter not working in xiaomi mobile

Tags: java, android

I created a sync adapter to sync data from android mobile to a server at interval. The adapter is working perfectly in all android devices except Redmi note 4. Tried with changing different different settings in Redmi note 4 but of no use.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your code? error messages?

Comment: E/SyncManager: Bind attempt failed - target: ComponentInfo{com.parcelbhej.android/com.parcelbhej.android.core.services.datasync.SyncService}

Comment: Hi, good question, but for clues, start to look over there [mcve], then edit your question and I am pretty sure, there will be someone, who will be able to provide you more steps for solution

Answer (score 2):

Following code is typical registering code syncAdaptor Service

```
     <service
            android:name="com.example.android.datasync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
     </service>
```

The attribute **android:process=":sync"** tells the system to run the Service in a global shared process named sync. If you have multiple sync adapters in your app they can share this process, which reduces overhead.

if you **remove this attribute** from Service tag, that will work on Xiami phone

Comment: This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the security app. Although it would require you to root. [Here's some further reading](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/04/11/remove-system-apps-from-xiaomi-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

The Xiaomi's Security app blocking the service. Check it, and enable the service running. But I don't know the real solution